# How do I add MonadLogger to my Free monad transformer stack?

Tags: haskell, logging, monad-transformers, free-monad

I already asked this question [here](https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/logger/issues/76), but I thought I would try SO as well.

How do I add `MonadLogger` to this Free monad transformer stack?

```
newtype Craft a = Craft { unCraft :: ReaderT CraftEnv (FreeT CraftDSL IO) a }
  deriving ( Functor, Monad, MonadIO, Applicative
           , MonadReader CraftEnv, MonadFree CraftDSL, MonadThrow)
```

I was able to add `MonadThrow` without issue; I was hoping adding `MonadLogger` would be just as easy.

I tried adding it and I get this error:

```
No instance for (MonadLogger (FreeT CraftDSL IO))
  arising from the 'deriving' clause of a data type declaration
```

If I define an instance:

```
instance MonadLogger (FreeT CraftDSL IO) where
  monadLoggerLog a b c d = Trans.lift $ monadLoggerLog a b c d
```

I get this error:

```
Could not deduce (MonadLogger IO)
  arising from a use of ‘monadLoggerLog’
```

[Here](https://github.com/joehillen/craft-monadfree/blob/master/app/Main.hs#L34) is a link to basic example of what I'm working on that compiles.

Comment: How do you want to do logging with IO? Clearly there is no instance for IO, so you'd have to write it yourself. If you want to *actually* add it to your type, then you should add another layer - `LoggerT` in this case I presume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `LoggingT` into the base of the stack works right away, but judging from

> No instance for (MonadLogger (FreeT CraftDSL IO))
>     arising from the 'deriving' clause of a data type declaration

you want to log stuff in your DSL do-blocks. For this we need to make `FreeT` an instance of `MonadLogger`:

```
instance (MonadLogger m, Functor f) => MonadLogger (FreeT f m) where
    monadLoggerLog loc source level msg = lift $ monadLoggerLog loc source level msg
```

Thanks to `LoggingT` already be an instance of `MonadLogger`, the `(MonadLogger m) => MonadLogger (FreeT f m)` constraint holds for your `Craft` type.

This code compiled for me, but since you didn't provide a minimal testcase i'm not sure if it really works.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. Here is my example with all the plumbing hooked up. https://github.com/joehillen/craft-monadfree/blob/loggingt/app/Main.hs

Answer (score 1):

Add `LoggingT` into the transformer stack, i.e.

```
newtype Craft a = Craft { unCraft :: ReaderT CraftEnv (LoggingT (FreeT CraftDSL IO)) a }
  deriving ( Functor, Monad, MonadIO, Applicative
           , MonadReader CraftEnv, MonadFree CraftDSL, MonadThrow, MonadLogger)
```

or if you need logging in interpretation of DSL:

```
newtype Craft a = Craft { unCraft :: ReaderT CraftEnv (FreeT CraftDSL (LoggingT IO)) a }
```

If there are missing instances, then you need to write them by hand, as `free` and `monad-logger` package don't provide instances for each others transformers.

Comment: "If there are missing instances, then you need to write them by hand" I'm aware. I'm asking "Which?" and "How?"